# Calculate variance of a subset

Tags: statistics

I have two sets of products A + B in the same product category. I have the overall and A's N, mean and variance. Can I calculate the variance of B with this?

I noticed [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29170/how-to-compute-standard-deviation-of-difference-between-two-data-sets) answer, but I wonder whether in this case A and B are independent since they are products in the same product category?

```
+------------------+---------+--------+------------+-------------+
| Product category | Product |   N    |    Mean    |  Variance   |
+------------------+---------+--------+------------+-------------+
| Z                | A       |    173 |  0.3475723 | 0.00291849  |
| Z                | A+B     |  42938 |  0.2744357 | 0.009905348 |
| Z                | B       |  42765 |  0.2741398 | ?           |
+------------------+---------+--------+------------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

Let us denote the sample variance of Product A items as $$s_A^2 = \frac{1}{N_A - 1} \sum_{i=1}^{N_A} (A_i - \mu_A)^2,$$ and the sample variance of product B items as $$s_B^2 = \frac{1}{N_B - 1} \sum_{i=1}^{N_B} (B_i - \mu_B)^2,$$ where $N_A$, $N_B$ are the sample sizes for each product; $A_1, A_2, \ldots, A_{N_A}$ and $B_1, B_2, \ldots, B_{N_B}$ are the observations in each sample; and $\mu_A$ and $\mu_B$ are the sample means of each sample.

We then also have $$s_{A+B}^2 = \frac{1}{N - 1} \left( \sum_{i=1}^{N_A} (A_i - \mu)^2 + \sum_{i=1}^{N_B} (B_i - \mu)^2 \right),$$ where $N = N_A + N_B$ is the pooled sample size, and $$\mu = \frac{1}{N} \left( \sum_{i=1}^{N_A} A_i + \sum_{i=1}^{N_B} B_i \right) = \frac{N_A \mu_A + N_B \mu_B}{N}$$ is the pooled mean.  Your question is to compute $s_B^2$ given the quantities $s_A^2$, $\mu_A$ $\mu_B$ and $s_{A+B}^2$.  To this end, it is clear that we must decompose the pooled variance somehow.  Note $$(A_i - \mu)^2 = ((A_i - \mu_A) + (\mu_A - \mu))^2 = (A_i - \mu_A)^2 + 2(\mu_A - \mu)(A_i - \mu_A) + (\mu_A - \mu)^2,$$ so that $$\sum_{i=1}^{N_A} (A_i - \mu)^2 = (N_A - 1) s_A^2 + 2(\mu_A - \mu) (N_A \mu_A - N_A \mu_A) + N_A (\mu_A - \mu)^2 \\ = (N_A - 1) s_A^2 + N_A (\mu_A - \mu)^2.$$  Similarly, $$\sum_{i=1}^{N_B} (B_i - \mu)^2 = (N_B - 1) s_B^2 + N_B (\mu_B - \mu)^2 .$$  It immediately follows that $$(N - 1) s_{A+B}^2 = (N_A - 1) s_A^2 + (N_B - 1) s_B^2 + N_A (\mu_A - \mu)^2 + N_B (\mu_B - \mu)^2,$$ from which we can solve for $s_B^2$ in terms of the other quantities.

It is worth noting that $$\mu_A - \mu = \frac{(N_A + N_B) \mu_A - N_A \mu_A - N_B \mu_B}{N} = \frac{N_B}{N} (\mu_A - \mu_B),$$ similarly $$\mu_B - \mu = \frac{N_A}{N} (\mu_B - \mu_A),$$ consequently $$(N-1) s_{A+B}^2 = (N_A - 1) s_A^2 + (N_B - 1) s_B^2 + \frac{N_A N_B}{N} (\mu_A - \mu_B)^2.$$

Comment: So from what I understand I can calculate the variance of B with ((42938-1)*0.009905348 - (173-1)*0.00291849 - ((0.3475723 - 0.2741398)^2)*(42765*173)/42765)/(42765-1) ? This results in 0.009911867 while I know the variance is 0.009911955 . Why is that?